Colored ellipse in TikZ
I am trying to find the color scheme of the figure below in my code:

The code I have written is given below:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0]
% Axes
\draw (-1,0) -- (12,0);

% First ellipse and circles
\fill [yellow!70!green] (1,0) ellipse (1.5cm and 0.5cm);
\draw [green!70!black] (1,0) ellipse (1.5cm and 0.5cm);
\filldraw[green!40!red] (0.2,0) circle (5pt);
\filldraw[black] (1.8,0) circle (5pt);

% Second ellipse and circles
\fill [yellow!70!green] (5,0) ellipse (1.5cm and 0.5cm);
\draw [green!70!black] (5,0) ellipse (1.5cm and 0.5cm);
\filldraw[green!40!red] (4.2,0) circle (5pt);
\filldraw[black] (5.8,0) circle (5pt);

% Third ellipse and circles
\fill [yellow!70!green] (9,0) ellipse (1.5cm and 0.5cm);
\draw [green!70!black] (9,0) ellipse (1.5cm and 0.5cm);
\filldraw[green!40!red] (8.2,0) circle (5pt);
\filldraw[black] (9.8,0) circle (5pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{} \label{fig:illustration}
\end{figure}
\end{document}

I could not find the correct scheme which created the colored ellipse and filled circle as given in the diagram. Can anyone please help me with this? Thank you!

\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\definecolor{einner}{RGB}{250,240,170}
\definecolor{eouter}{RGB}{200,220,160}
\definecolor{cinner}{RGB}{240,230,90}
\definecolor{couter}{RGB}{75,170,95}
\foreach \shift in{1, 5, 9}
  \shadedraw[xshift=\shift cm, draw=gray, very thick, inner color=einner, outer color=eouter] (1,0) ellipse[x radius=1.5cm, y radius=0.5cm];
\draw[ultra thick] (-1,0) -- (12,0);
\foreach \shift in{1, 5, 9}{
  \shade[xshift=\shift cm, inner color=cinner, outer color=couter] (0.2,0) circle[radius=8pt];
  \shade[xshift=\shift cm, inner color=cinner, outer color=couter] (1.8,0) circle[radius=8pt];
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


